# add files with period in name to .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a problem with creating some entries for the `.gitignore` file. There are directories with `.` in their names, like so:

```
Thing1.This/bin  
Thing1.That/bin 
Thing1.TheOther/bin
```

I want to exclude the bin directories. These directories can be added explicitly, but there are a lot which would make this tedious. I also tried using both these lines, but neither of them worked either:

```
*/bin
[Bb]in
```

How can this be specified?

I'm working on Windows 7.

Comment: The GCC compiler I work with creates 'prog.dSYM' directories (with multiple sub-directories) for each single-file program `prog` I create.  I have `*.dSYM` in my `.gitignore` file; the `*.dSYM` directories are never mentioned by `git`.

Comment: bin/ does not catch these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran:

```
$ for number in $(seq 1 9); do mkdir -p Thing$number.Thing/bin; done
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   makefile
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   b+tree
#   b+tree.cpp
#   cswap.c
#   qs.c
#   qs2.c
#   qs3.c
#   select.c
#   shm
#   shm.c
#   sleepers-awake.c
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$
```

There is no content in the directories, so there's nothing for `git` to track, so they are not listed as needing to be tracked.  I added files to the directories:

```
$ for d in Thing?.Thing/bin; do cp qs.c $d; done
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   makefile
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Thing1.Thing/
#   Thing2.Thing/
#   Thing3.Thing/
#   Thing4.Thing/
#   Thing5.Thing/
#   Thing6.Thing/
#   Thing7.Thing/
#   Thing8.Thing/
#   Thing9.Thing/
#   b+tree
#   b+tree.cpp
#   cswap.c
#   qs.c
#   qs2.c
#   qs3.c
#   select.c
#   shm
#   shm.c
#   sleepers-awake.c
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$
```

The directories now show up in `git` as needing to be added.  I edited `.gitignore` to add `Thing*.Thing/bin` thus:

```
Thing*.Thing/bin
*.a
*.dSYM
*.o
*.so
*~
a.out
core
posixver.h
timer.h
```

I reran `git status`:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   modified:   makefile
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   b+tree
#   b+tree.cpp
#   cswap.c
#   qs.c
#   qs2.c
#   qs3.c
#   select.c
#   shm
#   shm.c
#   sleepers-awake.c
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$
```

So, the regexes (globs?) can be made to work.  I also reran the test (after cleaning up the first one) using `*/bin` in `.gitignore`; same result — the pattern worked and suppressed the directories.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) with `git --version` reporting `1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)`.

Comment: I'm not sure that your example applies, though I could be mistaken. Your example has Thing*.Thing, whereas the structure I have is Thing.*. I've edited the original post to reflect more accurately the situation.

Comment: It would work with `Thing.*/bin` or `Thing*/bin` or any variant you're likely to think of, at least on my Mac.  The problem may be file name expansion on Windows, in some shape or form.  There are still remnants of the old 8.3 file name rules lurking around, and your directory names are long enough to break those (archaic) rules.  Try creating and ignoring `Thing1/bin/file.txt` (directories and a file).  Then see what happens with `Thing*/bin` in `.gitignore`.  Did you build `git` yourself or did you download it prebuilt?  (I'd guess the latter.)

Comment: Downloaded git prebuilt.

Comment: There is no directory `Thing1/bin`. The directory name has a . in it.

Comment: In standard `git` running on Unix, the presence or absence of the dot is largely immaterial.  If it matters on Windows, fine; add it.  For a test directory, try `Thing1.dir/bin` which meets 8.3 and your criteria (contains a dot). I don't have (or want) Windows 7.  I'm trying to help despite my reservations about the system.  I'll leave you to sink or swim on your own if you prefer.  You are expected to use your nous and try fitting into the 8.3 paradigm.  Does the ignoring work when you have a name without the dot?

Comment: Created file `Thing1.directory/bin/MyTestFile.txt`  Added pattern `Thing1.*/bin/MyTestFile.txt`  and it sees it

Comment: I just need to experiment with statements like `directory.*/*.*.*.*/bin/*' until I've got everything covered.

Comment: Are you so young you don't know what the [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) limits are? I'm sorry; I suppose I should know that some people using SO are too young to have suffered through that. When people say 8.3, they mean up to eight characters before a dot, then up to three characters after the dot — like `Thing1.bin` (which is a 6.3 name, within the limits of 8.3), and unlike `Thing1.directory` (which is a 6.9 name and not within the limits of 8.3 names). Since I can't experiment on your machine for you, I do mean that you might need to experiment under guidance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add `bin` directories in any subdirectory to gitignore, you can use this syntax:

```
**/bin/
```

It ignores all bin folders in repository. From the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
>   example, "`**`/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same
>   as pattern "foo". "`**`/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
>   anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".